# Lookup of the inheritance chain with typescript classes

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

We have an inhouse "framework" which builds "classes" for ES5 like this:

```
var MyClass = ourClass({
  extends: Base,
  constructor: function MyClass(...){...}
  static: {},
  ...
})

// later somewhere
var myClassInstance = new MyClass(...);
```

This mechanism decorates the constructor (which is returned) with the static properties and the "staticChain" of things it inherits from (the constructor functions).

Given the hierarchy Base -> Specialized -> EvenMoreSpecialized, `EvenMoreSpecialized.staticChain === [EvenMoreSpecialized, Specialized, Base, Object]`. Now if an instance `theInstance` of `EvenMoreSpecialized` exists, and we call `theInstance.static('aField')`, the first property 'aField' defined on the constructor functions inherited from in order will be returned.

I want to look for possibilities to use TS/ES6 classes instead, but so far, static() has been a roadblock. The feature is in use in live code.

The question is how I can profit from TS for this and use the class keyword, or if it can't be done without major hassles.

The signature for the static() function would probably be like this:

```
static(identifier:string):any
```

Is there any way to detect if somebody misspelled the identifier at compile time? I can't imagine there is...? Maybe narrow down that `any`?

#### a more comprehensive example:

```
var Base = ourClass({
  extends: Object,
  constructor: function Base(){},
  static: {
    secret: null
  }
})

var Specialized = ourClass({
  extends: Base, 
  constructor: function Specialized() {};
  static: {
    secret: '12345'
});
var EvenMoreSpecialized = ourClass({
  extends: EvenMoreSpecialized,
  static: {
    secret: '23456'
  }
});

var base = new Base();
// base.constructor.staticChain === [Base, Object];
base.static('secret'); // => null; Base.secret

var specialized = new Specialized();
// specialized.constructor.staticChain === [Specialized, Base, Object]
specialized.static('secret'); // => '12345'; Specialized.secret

var even = new EvenMoreSpecialized();
// even.constructor.staticChain === [EvenMoreSpecialized, Specialized, Base, Object]
even.static('secret'); // => '23456'; EvenMoreSpecialized.secret
```

Comment: I think it may help to add a few examples, it's not obvious to me what behavior you expect from these things. What is `staticChain` used for? If `theInstance` is an instance, how do you call it as `theInstance('aField')` implying it is a function?

Comment: I added some usage of the static() method and corrected the text above `theInstance.static(...)`. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

One could make a static method lookup that interrogates the prototype and constructor chain to build a cache for each prototype of static methods present in the constructors, maybe like this? (Compiles with strict typescript settings and runs with node)

One could also write the static cache initialization as a decorator but since the EcmaScript specification on those isn't ready *yet* the typescript decorator API is still subject to changes. Once finalized that might be a more elegant solutions.

(Yes you will loose type safety but for legacy purposes it should work)

```
class Base {
    staticMethod(m:string):(...any:any[])=>any {
        // check if we already have a static cache, if not build it.
        if (!("_staticCache" in this)) {
            // our cache object
            let statics=Object.create(null);
            // collection method
            let collect=(x:any)=>{
                let proto=Object.getPrototypeOf(x.prototype);
                // first try to collect any parent statics
                if (proto)
                    collect(proto.constructor);
                // then collect the current statics
                for (let prop in x) {
                    statics[prop]=x[prop];
                }
            }
            // initiate collection
            collect(this.constructor);
            // now set an unenumerable property on the prototype.
            Object.defineProperty(
                Object.getPrototypeOf(this),
                "_staticCache",
                {enumerable:false,value:statics});
        }
        return (this as any)._staticCache[m];
    }
}
class Foo extends Base {

    static fooOnly(x:string) {
        console.log("fooOnly in foo with arg "+x);
    }
    static fooBar() {
        console.log("fooBar in foo");
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    static fooBar() {
        console.log("fooBar in bar");
    }
    static barOnly() {
        console.log("barOnly in bar");
    }
}

let test=new Bar();

test.staticMethod("fooOnly")("Hello");  // calls method in foo
test.staticMethod("fooBar")();          // calls method in bar
test.staticMethod("barOnly")();         // calls method in bar
```

Answer (score 0):

The impression I get is that you want to assign a fixed value and have your class hierarchy return the closest value. Which *sounds* a lot like standard class inheritance behaviour.

You didn't mention any requirement for value mutability, so there's a few approaches I can think of. One of them is prototypical, the other is assignment. They both work out the same in terms of inheritance.

These examples use the `keyof` keyword, which was introduced in [TypeScript 2.1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html).

```
class Base {
    value: number;
    name : string;
    readonly otherValue: number = 123;
    /**
     * Returns the value of this by the key provided.
     * @param key - Restricted to keys of the class inheriting.
     */
    static<K extends keyof this>(key: K): this[K] {
        return this[key];
    }
}
// Setting prototype assigns shared value.
Base.prototype.value = 123;

class InheritFromBase extends Base {
    // Splits separate values.
    readonly otherValue: number = 456;
    anotherValue: number;
}

InheritFromBase.prototype.value = 345;

class WorkingExample extends InheritFromBase {

}

let base = new Base();
// Compile Error, Base.value is number and cannot be compared to string.
base.static('value') == 'bob';
// Compiles Fine; Base.name is string and can be compared to string.
base.static('name') === 'bob';
// Compile Error, AnotherValue is not available on base.
base.static('anotherValue');
let ex = new WorkingExample();
// Compiles Fine because InheritFromBase has anotherValue.
ex.static('anotherValue');
base.value = 255;
let result = Base.prototype.value === base.value; // Returns False; assigning Base.value does not overwrite prototype.
```

You can also designate a separate object, IF you know the potential static keys at design time and are willing to duplicate inherited values.

```
interface IStaticOptions {
    optionA?: string;
    optionB?: number;
    optionC?: string;
}

class ThirdBase {
    value: number;
    anotherValue: number;
    staticOptions: IStaticOptions;
    static<K extends keyof IStaticOptions>(key: K): IStaticOptions[K] {
        return this.staticOptions[key];
    }
    staticTwo<K extends keyof this>(key: K): this[K] {
        return this[key];
    }
}
```

This all assumes you have the ability to replace the entirety of your existing class framework with this new approach (like you said, using this instead of the framework). If you do not, this is not a solution.

Personally, I prefer the prototype/assignment approach in the first example.